# Stop OS from killing my Process

Tags: android, android-intent, process, kill-process

I have an application in which I am calling `ACTION_SEND` intent from my `main activity`. Everything works fine but when I return to my main activity from `ACTION_SEND` intent then `main activity` starts its execution from `onCreate()` method but I want it to be started from `onRestart()` method.
I think its bcz a OS kills my activity to free up space.
So is there any way rather than using `Service` So that I can stop OS from killing my activity ?

Answer (score 0):

> I think its bcz a OS kills my activity to free up space

Possibly. You might be doing something yourself to destroy your activity (e.g., calling `finish()` after calling `startActivity()` for your `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`).

> So is there any way rather than using Service So that I can stop OS from killing my activity ?

No. Even a service may not help. Your process can be terminated at any time, for any reason, including the user deciding to terminate it via a task manager or the recent-tasks list. Also, if the user rotates the screen or causes another configuration change while in whatever app they started via `ACTION_SEND`, your activity that called `startActivity()` with `ACTION_SEND` will be recreated due to the configuration change.

You cannot assume that `onRestart()` will be called. In general, I consider `onRestart()` to be a code smell for just this reason.

Comment: I have checked my code and I am not calling finish() after startActivity(). And one more thing is that onDestroy() method of main activity never gets called but when I press back button from ACTION_SEND Intent(like Bluetooth activity), it automatically starts main activity from onCreate(). What I am not getting is that how can  activity starts from onCreate() without calling onDestroy(). Please put some light on it.

Comment: @Vikalp: "but when I press back button from ACTION_SEND Intent(like Bluetooth activity), it automatically starts main activity from onCreate()" -- that means your process was terminated. Activities do not have to be called with `onDestroy()`. Only ones that are finished, via BACK or you calling `finish()` or similar means, will be destroyed and go through `onDestroy()`. Any running activities in your process when the process is terminated are not destroyed.

Comment: Ok I got it but Isn't there any way that I can resume state of my main activity to where I left of ?

Comment: @Vikalp: That depends on what the "state" is. `onSaveInstanceState()` should be called on your activity around the time the `ACTION_SEND` activity comes to the foreground. You are welcome to put stuff in that `Bundle`. You should get that `Bundle` back in `onCreate()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` of your new activity instance, since the user is effectively navigating back to a specific spot. This is standard activity lifecycle stuff, see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#SavingActivityState

Comment: I have used a Service Class to do my work and that solved my problem. I bound my main activity to service class and now OS isn't killing my activity (OS will only kill my activity under extreme memory requirement)